# ~/.subversion/auth/svn.simple/<hash> algorithm?

Tags: svn, authentication, client

What is the algorithm for determining the file name in ~/.subversion/auth/svn.simple/ directory?

I am trying to setup subversion to authenticate non-interactively and to have it use an a priori created file for authentication (as opposed to having to authenticate manually for the first time). I cannot configure the server, only the client.

As an experiment, I manually authenticated to see what file is being created. It is trivial for me to create the file ahead of time, but I can't find an obvious way to generate the correct file name. For example:

cat <file> | md5

does not generate the file name :/. Similarly hashing the svn:realmstring or variations thereof fails to generate the correct file name.

In other words, given:

```
$ cat ~/.subversion/auth/svn.simple/a67f7e17e9b4059f367743be8f30c336

K 8
username
V 3
joe
K 8
password
V 4
blah
K 15
svn:realmstring
V 45
<https://svn.domain.com:443> Joe's repository
END
```

What do I need to hash in order to get `a67f7e17e9b4059f367743be8f30c336`?

Comment: Is using the `--username` and `--password` command line options out of the question (instead of stored credentials)?

Comment: yes, this is part of setting up a vagrant box for the user, so the goal is to be non-interactive... I've been able to determine that "Subversion stores the auth data according to the auth realm string and repo root url", but still looking for the exact algorithm :/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The answer is to md5 the svn:realmstring.

Given:

```
<https://svn.apache.org:443> ASF Committers
```

verify hash via (assuming that your MD5 utility is `md5sum` for example, on a Mac it is `md5`)

```
echo -n "<https://svn.apache.org:443> ASF Committers" | md5sum
> d3c8a345b14f6a1b42251aef8027ab57
```

Comment: For reference the code that does this is in svn_auth__file_path() which is in subversion/libsvn_subr/config_auth.c aka https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/subversion/libsvn_subr/config_auth.c  Your example in your question doesn't line up with the actual hash probably because you cahnged it.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the example (now that I know what the answer is :D)

Comment: @wilfred-hughes `md5sum` does not exist on a Mac :/ so your edit breaks the answer

Comment: Sorry about that. Shame there's no cross-platform way of doing it.

Comment: @WilfredHughes `openssl dgst -md5` works the same on any platform with `openssl`, which includes Mac.